# Eliminar datos de un archivo

Tags: c++, c, archivo

Hola estoy creando una agenda en la que se guardan los contactos en un archivo, para añadir los contactos utilizo una estructura la cual guardo como contacto en el archivo y cada esctructura representa un contacto. Quiero que la agenda tenga la posibilidad de eliminar un contacto pero me he topado con el problema de eliminar el contacto del archivo, para encontrar el contacto a borrar solicito nombre y apellido del contacto y lo busco en el archivo, el problema es que no se como podría eliminiar la estructura del archivo una vez la haya encontrado. Como podría eliminarlo? Les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Que tal si nos compartes el codigo que tienes, asi se nos hara mas facil ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es leer uno por uno todos los contactos y ir guardandolos uno por uno en tu struct. Despues con Wt o wb dependiendo de si tu archivo es binario o de texto borras todos los datos que hay en tu archivo y escribes todos los que has guardado anteriormente en el struct menos el que quieres borrar.

lo puede hacer con un while para leerlos y con un for que tenga dentro un if para escribirlos. Al for le pones que se repita el número de veces correspondiente al número de contactos que ha leido en el archivo. Luego dentro del for pones un if que sirva para que solo se escriba el contacto [i] si el nombre es diferente al que quieres eliminar lo escribe, si es igual pues no lo escribe y pasa al siguiente así lo habrás eliminado de tu archivo. Pero ten en cuenta que seguirá en el struct.